# Stopping visitors browser from loading website from cache

Tags: css, html, browser-cache

I updated the images and stylesheets on my website, but I am getting phone calls from clients saying my layout looks weird. When they refresh the page, it looks normal.

How do I stop their browsers from loading my website from cache?

Comment: Are there any caching mechanism used directly by your site?  I'm thinking of CMS caching, in particular.

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files) is a good read.

Comment: In addition to Mohamed's answer, you can also put this html in the head section: `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use meta tags to tell the browser not to cache the page:

You can also generate raw headers. 
Please read [HTTP specifications](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
<?
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: You might want to add that this is php code ;)

Comment: when you see this ==> <? ?>

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't it php then?

Comment: Of course it is PHP. Whenever you see those.

Comment: Actually you normally see `<?php ?>` instead, but my point was that you might want to say it is php, given the fact that someone unfamiliar with it may not know.

Comment: yes, you are correct for this one.

Answer (score 1):

use one of the [static file versioning](https://www.google.com/search?q=static+file+versioning) techniques

such as adding a querystring to the static file `/img/image1.jpg?v=1.0` or rename the file `/img/image1_1.0.jpg`

this applies to any image, JavaScript, or CSS files